# Data Flow Task gera arquivo Excel em branco - SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, servidor, services, ssis

Eu tenho um processo no SSIS que pega as informações de uma tabela e exporta para um arquivo xlsx. Ocorre que, ao rodar o Job pelo SQL Server Agent, muitas vezes o arquivo é gerado em branco, mesmo tendo conteúdo na tabela (não é sempre que isso acontece). Quando isso acontece eu abro o SSIS e rodo na mão, e o arquivo vem preenchido da forma adequada. Gostaria de saber o que poderia estar ocasionando isso? No Data Flow Task eu tenho um data conversion entre o Data Source e o Excel Destination, que converte as linhas para String, mas não vi nada de errado nesta task também. Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Olá Paulo, por acaso tu já importou novamente o DTS para dentro do SSIS ? Será que quando tu "roda na mão" não está executando uma versão diferente da que está no SSIS ?

Comment: Ricardo, eu rodo pela própria Solution do SSIS... é a mesma DTS para a qual o Job está apontando.